# Windows backup "Volumes larger than" error

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup, gpt

A week ago I started getting the Windows Backup error 0x807800B4, stating "Volumes larger than 2088958 megabytes cannot be protected." I'm not sure what this is referring to. My system volume is a 256gb SSD and the drive all my data is on is a 3TB hard disk. The consumed space is only a couple hundred gigabytes.

I'm backing up over the network to a 6tb SMB volume. I've been running Windows Backup on this machine successfully for a couple months and this started happening with no hardware change. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Windows Backup screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I was suffering from that same (or at least a similar) issue](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5070298#5070298). While reading up on the issue, I read a lot of reports about this issue.

There are 2 possible issues here.

1. Volumes larger than 2TB can not be backed up.
2. You can not backup from or to volumes the use sectors larger than 512B

To solve 1, you can tell Windows Backup to not back up the entire volume, but only selected folders from the drive.

To my understanding, there is no solution to proper problem 2. We ended up purchasing new 2TB drives for our backup issue and I've read of several reports where people ended up doing the same.
And, yes, this also applies when the backup target is accessed through SMB.

Comment: Apparently at some point it decided my 3TB volume was a drive that needed to have a system image generated. Had to go through the custom settings to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error message when trying to backup my new computer (Windows 7 OS).  I thought my WD external hard drive was not large enough so I bought a new WD Elements 3TB.
I still had the same problem.

I tried reformatting and re-partitioning the external hard drive and still had the same problem. After much research on the web I came to understand it was not my external hard drive at all, but MS Windows Backup that was to blame!

I downloaded the free version of [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) backup software and – voilà!

Complete backup and system image with no error messages!

Answer (score 0):

I have backed up Exchange on a 2TB volume which was 16GB over the limit.  In order to backup Exchange the entire drive must be selected.  However I then added exclusions for the Windows folder and a few others in order to hit the 16GB which then allowed the backup to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this started happening because I created a junction point (hard link) for a system folder (C:\Windows\Installer) and moved it to another drive in order to make some free space on my system's SSD.

In my case, Windows correctly attempted to backup both drives when I enabled the option to include system files in your backup. The other drive exceeds the 2GB limit, so Windows backup can't process those files.

I believe this will also happen if you ask Windows backup to explicitly include folders on any other drives that exceed 2GB, or if your system drive is bigger than 2GB. To work around the latter, you could create a partition for your system drive less than 2GB and move Windows there. I haven't tested this but expect it should work.